# checking the internet connection and display the result in the TextView class

Tags: android

I wrote the following code that if **the internet connection** was yes, the `textView` object displays **Connect** and if not It displays **Disconnect**.

But the following code do not work well.Is the cause of the problem from the **Null** value?

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    EditText editText;
NetworkInfo networkInfo;
    String string;
    ConnectivityManager connectivityManager = null;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.textView);
networkInfo = connectivityManager.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE);
if(networkInfo.isConnected())
  editText.setText("Connect");
        else if(!networkInfo.isConnected())
    editText.setText("Disconnect");
    }
```

Comment: what do you mean by `is not working well` ?

Comment: I get "stopped unexpectedly. please try again". this code is short. please and please test the code.I think the code is correct.

Comment: Also when I use the  **ConnectivityManager connectivityManager = (ConnectivityManager)getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);** I get the same error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code connectivityManager is null. Try this.

```
connectivityManager = (ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
NetworkInfo activeNetworkInfo = connectivityManager.getActiveNetworkInfo();
boolean isConnected = activeNetworkInfo != null && activeNetworkInfo.isConnected();
```

Comment: Thank you. I added your code. Of course, android studio says  that i should use **private Context context;**  to use the your code, Because **context** object in your code was red. But again I get the same error.I think the problem is from the my IDE . which version do you use?

Comment: I am using Eclipse IDE. Since you are writing it in Activity then Remove context from that line just write (ConnectivityManager)getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE).